# todonotes crashes because too many on list

Tags: errors, packages, todonotes

I am been using the package `\usepackage{todonotes}` but have ran into a problem with the `\listoftodos`.. 
My list has become above one page, and it seems to to not compile when it goes above this limit..  Any fix on that issue?

Log:
http://pastebin.com/gaNFiix1

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Particularly, with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\sometext}{
\lipsum[1] \todo{An item}
\lipsum[2] \todo{Another item}
\lipsum[3] \todo{A third item}
\lipsum[4] \todo{Yet another item}
\lipsum[5] \todo{Item 5}}
\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\sometext
\end{document}`, I have a two-page list and no problems with MacTeX 2014.

Comment: I constructed a similar MWE with a 3 page list of todos.  It compiles without problem on Win8.1, Miktex 2.9, and Texmaker 4.4.1.  You need to try a similar MWE as I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Facetious solution: *do* some of the *todo*s... :-)

Comment: I suspect a fragile command in a todo note.

Comment: All my todos contains only chars.